# Is it possible to use stream urls instead of downloading media to disk when instantiating an AVAudioPlayerNode?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, avaudioengine, avaudiofile

We are using Amazon Cloudfront to stream audio to the iOS application. We need specific functionality that is only available on the AVAudioEngine which is why we are trying to instantiate AVAudioPlayerNode. The problem is that it appears that the media needs to be downloaded on the device for the AVAudioPlayerNode to work as intentded. Is this a limitation of the AVAudioPlayerNode itself or is there a way to stream audio files from a remote location?

Currently the implementation we are going off of is downloading the media to the drive and then deleting it once we are done with it which obviously has several limitations especially in regards to download times.